# Not stopping at server side breakpoints whilst Debugging classic asp with Visual Studio 2005

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

The website is set up locally on my IIS 5.1 on xp.
Application protection is set to low within IIS so the asp is run inside the inetinfo.exe process.

I start debugging , attach to the inetinfo.exe process and refresh the page in the browser so the page reloads and reruns the server side code. Non of the breakpoints get hit. There's no warnings around the breakpoints to alert me to an issue.

Have read http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/02/07/527293.aspx#552237 and similar posts, whilst helpful in getting me this far, I've still got this one outstanding issue.

It's been years since I've done classic asp , and I've never done it with VS 2005, so I may be making a nube mistake.

Any suggestions, comments very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled asp server side debugging in IIS?  Hidden somewhere in the properties... sorry for lack of detail.

Comment: Bingo! Yes, it was hidden in the properties->virtual directory tab->configuation button->debugging tab.

Cheers Paddy

Comment: No problem.  It's quite annoying when that doesn't work.  Be wary of upgrading to 2008 - classic asp debugging gets a lot worse.